# How make a custom Retrofit ConverterFactory to transform ReponseBody to a new ResponseBody?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'd like to transform the answer of a service which is codified in "windows-1252" to "unicode". I am trying to do using a custom converter factory in retrofit to acomplish that work. My custom converter try to intercept the ResponseBody class, change the character codification, and return a new ResponseBody to retrofit to be processed. 
But it didn't work. Apparently, retrofit built in converters intercept first the ResponseBody class and it can't be processed again. 
Is there any way to avoid that behavior?

Note: I can get it using a map function when I have the response but I'd like to learn to do in retrofit.

This is my code.

```
AnsiconverterFactory.java
-------------------------

public class AnsiConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    public static AnsiConverterFactory create() {
        return new AnsiConverterFactory();
    }

    private AnsiConverterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (type == ResponseBody.class) {
            return AnsiResponseBodyConverter.INSTANCE;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return super.stringConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
AnsiResponseBodyConverter.java
------------------------------
public class AnsiResponseBodyConverter implements Converter<ResponseBody, ResponseBody> {
    static final AnsiResponseBodyConverter INSTANCE = new AnsiResponseBodyConverter();

    @Override
    public ResponseBody convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        Log.d("CONVERTER", " En convert de responsebodyconverter");
        final CharBuffer todo = Charset.forName("windows-1252").decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(value.bytes()));
        return ResponseBody.create(value.contentType(), todo.toString());

    }
}
```

And the use in the app:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://...some webservice here")
                .addConverterFactory(BitmapConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(AnsiConverterFactory.create())
                .client(clientBuilder.build())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Comment: Can you add a okhttp interceptor to convert responsebody?

Comment: Yes. I did it. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem using an interceptor in okhttp. This is the code:

```
class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        ResponseBody body = response.body();
        if (body.contentType().equals(MediaType.parse("text/csv"))) {
            final CharBuffer todo = Charset.forName("windows-1252").decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(body.bytes()));
            body = ResponseBody.create(body.contentType(), todo.toString());
            Response.Builder builder = response.newBuilder();
            return  builder.headers(response.headers())
                    .body(body)
                    .build();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

And this just before Retrofit build.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());
```

Comment: before call ResponseBody‘s method,check null or not.